# On Whatsapp can I know if I am in someone's contact list based on the "security code" messages?

Tags: contacts, security, whatsapp-messenger

Can I know if someone has me in their contacts based on the security code messages that are sent when there is a change or is that based on whether I have them in my contacts?

I want to know if someone still has me in their contacts, I have their number saved and when I opened the chat I saw the list of security code changes from their side going back 4 years or so (most recent one from this year). Does this mean they still have my number saved or is that because I have theirs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to see that other contacts' [Security Code Change Notification](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/security-and-privacy/security-code-change-notification/?lang=en), it means that you are they have you as a contact as.

> These codes are unique to each chat and can be compared between people in each chat to verify that the messages you send to the chat are end-to-end encrypted.

If you have never communicated with a contact, there won't be any security codes exchanged between both of you. Meaning that you won't see changes that happened when they reinstall, update the app or change numbers.

> At times, the security codes used in end-to-end encryption might change. This can happen because you or your contact reinstalled WhatsApp or changed phones.